# One Modem One repeater, how i can define the printer?

Tags: network-printer, repeater, ssid

I have 1 modem and a repeater with different SSIDs. How can I define the printer which is installed on the modem on the PC which is connected to the repeater which is on an another SSID?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a repeater, then the IP addresses across the whole WLAN will be compatible. So you can just install the printer as if it were attached directly to the modem. The way to do this depends on the printer.

You don't say how the printer is attached. Is it connected via WiFi or via an ethernet cable? If it is USB connected then you may have completely different problems.

Some printers have a CD installer that finds the printer on the network. In that case, the installer will do the rest. Some HP printers expect you to connect the printer via USB to set up the WiFi side.

Once the printer has an IP address, you can always install it as a "local" printer. When asked for the port, create a new port and give it the printer's IP address. Of course, that implies the printer has a front panel display system that allows you to select the WiFi network and enter the password.